# jQuery mobile overlay theme semi transparent?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

Is it possible to change the opacity of a data overlay theme? For when a dialog box opens you can see the page still in the background but blurred or light?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add up `data-overlay-theme` attribute in your popup code like in the following example:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
    <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you may control the opacity of the overlay put on the background page by adding something like to your css like this:

```
.ui-popup-screen {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    opacity: 0.75 !important;
}
```